# Run next command in script after invoking singularity shell

Tags: bash, docker, shell, singularity-container

I have a shell script with multiple singularity commands in it
`myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh/

singularity shell -B /home/user/Desktop/ /home/user/image/some_image.simg
/home/user/miniconda/activate my_env
cd /app/app_folder/scripts
ls -ash
```

when i run the script it get stuck after the shell is invoked.

```
singularity>
```

However I want the subsequent commands to run in the invoked shell. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu are connecting to an interactive command shell inside a shell script, what you need is only execute the commands.

```
singularity exec ...
```

https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/cli/singularity_exec.html

Comment: This is correct, but that link is really old. Link for the current version are: https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/cli/singularity_exec.html and older version docs are available at https://sylabs.io/docs/

Answer (score 1):

So basically I had to replace `shell` with `exec` and save the subsequent commands in a different executable bash script `newscript.sh` which contains

```
#!/bin/sh

/home/user/miniconda/activate my_env
cd /app/app_folder/scripts
ls -ash
```

and then run `myscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

singularity exec -B /home/user/Desktop/ /home/user/image/some_image.simg bash newscript.sh
```

This method will run `newscript.sh` in the singularity shell after the singularity shell is invoked in `myscript.sh`